# how to set equal height for sliders in cols bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

first of my website has two sliders and each inside of a col like following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <div class="topSalon"><img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid"
                                               src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/images/2020/avatar/pic911_www.jahaniha.com_2.jpg"
                                               alt="First slide">
                        <div class="topSalonBody"><h3>سالن زیبایی سحر</h3>
                            <p>لورم ایپسوم یا طرح‌نما (به انگلیسی: Lorem ipsum) به متنی آزمایشی و بی‌معنی در صنعت چاپ،
                                صفحه‌آرایی و طراحی گرافیک گفته می‌شود. طراح گرافیک از این متن به عنوان عنصری از ترکیب
                                بندی برای پر کردن صفحه و ارایه اولیه شکل ظاهری و کلی طرح سفارش گرفته شده استفاده می
                                نماید، تا از نظر گرافیکی نشانگر چگونگی نوع و اندازه فونت و ظاهر متن باشد</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="active carousel-item">
                    <div class="topSalon"><img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid"
                                               src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/images/2020/avatar/Beauty-Secrets.jpg"
                                               alt="First slide">
                        <div class="topSalonBody"><h3>سالن بیتا منفرد</h3>
                            <p>توضیحات کوتاه</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" href="#"><span aria-hidden="true"
                                                                          class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span><span
                    class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a class="carousel-control-next" role="button" href="#"><span
                aria-hidden="true" class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" style="min-height: 300px;">
        <div class="carousel slide">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li class="active"></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item"><img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid"
                                                src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/images/slide/2020/4/1_28015.png"
                                                alt="First slide">
                    <div class="carousel-caption"><h3>اسلاید اول</h3>
                        <p>توضیحات کوتاه این اسلایدر 1</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item"><img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid"
                                                src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/images/slide/2020/4/2_11831.png"
                                                alt="First slide">
                    <div class="carousel-caption"><h3>اسلاید اول</h3>
                        <p>توضیحات کوتاه این اسلایدر 2</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="active carousel-item"><img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid"
                                                       src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/images/slide/2020/4/3_34880.png"
                                                       alt="First slide">
                    <div class="carousel-caption"><h3>اسلاید اول</h3>
                        <p>توضیحات کوتاه این اسلایدر 3</p></div>
                </div>

            <a class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" href="#"><span aria-hidden="true"
                                                                          class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span><span
                    class="sr-only">Previous</span></a><a class="carousel-control-next" role="button" href="#"><span
                aria-hidden="true" class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

custom css code :

```
.single-blog-post .read-more-btn {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 24px;
    left: 16px;
}

.top-salon-container {
    margin-top: 18px;
    border-radius: 12px !important;
    background-color: #f7f7ff !important;
    box-shadow: -9px 7px 30px -5px rgba(150,170,180,0.5);
    height: 97%;
    h2{
        color: #222a;
        background: linear-gradient(45deg, #d0d0d5, #e0e0e8);
        padding: 12px 16px;
        border-top-left-radius: 8px !important;
        border-top-right-radius: 8px !important;
    }

    .top-salon-item {
        padding: 8px;

        img {
            margin: 2px 0 2px 8px;
            border-radius: 12px !important;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        .info {
            padding: 12px 6px;
            h4 {
                padding-top: 10px;
                font-size: 22px;
                color: #858587;
            }
            p {
                text-align: justify;
            }
        }
    }


    @media (max-width: 1200px) {
        h2 {
            font-size: 1.75em;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
        h2 {
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }
    }

}


.topSalon {
    .topSalonBody {
        padding: 10px;
    }
}
```

I want to that height of right slider to be same with left slider, (height of sliders be equal) but it's not correct when text size of each right slider is different.

- **when text size is long**

[image: when text size is long]

---

- **when text size is short**

[image: when text size is short]

how can set same height to those in Any state?

Comment: Can you write your css code

Comment: @nourza edited my question